# Conditions for solution to equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have the following question in an exercise of linear fitting.
**Q.**
We have $n$ linearly independent known vectors $\textbf{a}_i$, $i = 1, . . . , n$, a known vector $\textbf{b}$, and an unknown vector $\textbf{x}$. All vectors are of dimension $m$. Under what conditions is there a solution to the following equation?
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \textbf{a}_i\textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{x}= \textbf{b}$$
Express in terms of $m$ and $n$.

---

**My attempt:**
Let $\textbf{A} = [\textbf{a}_1, ..., \textbf{a}_n]$, $m × n$ matrix.
So, $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \textbf{a}_i\textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{x} =\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T \textbf{x} =  \textbf{b}$.
Since $\textbf{a}_i$ are linearly independent vectors which form the columns of $\textbf{A}$, column rank of $\textbf{A}$ is $n$.
For equation $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T \textbf{x} =  \textbf{b}$, we have the following 3 cases considering the $m × m$ matrix $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T$:

**Case 1**: $m = n$
$rank(\textbf{A}) = n \implies rank(\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T) = n = m$
So, $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T$ is a full rank matrix, hence, invertible. So the equation has a unique solution.

**Case 2**: $m > n$
$rank(\textbf{A}) = n \implies rank(\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T) = n < m$
So, $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T$ is a rank deficient matrix. For a solution to exist, vector **b** must lie in the column space of matrix $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T$.

> (1) Can we express this in terms of $m$ and $n$?

**Case 3**: $m < n$
$rank(\textbf{A}) = n \implies rank(\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^T) = n > m$
This case of a matrix having a rank more than numbers of columns seems absurd generally.

> (2) But is it possible in linear fitting or in an overdetermined system, since we have more equations than unknowns?

> (3) What other conditions am I missing?

---

So, I am unable to answer the 3 open questions above. Kindly help me.

Comment: I upvoted to reverse a downvote.  In fact, even if there had been no downvote, I would still have upvoted.  The OP's question is clear, he used mathJax to format the question, and he showed **plenty** of work.  Personally, I don't know the answer.

Comment: I would request to down-voter to explain so that I can improve.

Comment: Unfortunately, mathSE is infected with occasional **anonymous** downvoters.  Personally, I regard your presentation as superior to about 95% of the presentations re the questions posted on this website.